# Application will not open

Tags: installation, package-management

I installed [Swami](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/amd64/swami/2.0.0+svn384-1) from the Software Center but when I try to open it, nothing happens.
What's going on here?

Comment: try running the application from a terminal - does any errors appear in the terminal?  If so, please add these to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like many MIDI applications, Swami requires the [JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org/) to be installed and running in order to operate.

Installing and configuring JACK is beyond the scope of this question. A good place to start learning about it is the [documentation for Ubuntu Studio](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio).